How to block Web3 Domains
There are some domains called "decentralized" (Web3), promoted by Unstoppable Domains and Ethereum Name Service, example:
.888
.anime
.bitcoin
.blockchain
.coin
.crypto
.dao
.eth

Is there any squid-cache or iptables rule (or other mechanism) that is capable of blocking these decentralized domains?
PS: From the little I have found on the subject, it is suggested to activate SSL traffic and Deep packet inspection (DPI), but without further details.

Why do you need to block them? Any normally configured client won't resolve them.

It will not resolve it, if it is a direct request from the browser (or google search), as DNS will not resolve it, however, there are browsers (brave, etc.) and browser extensions that allow connection to these domains.

Do you want to Block incoming or out going traffic

For squid
Open your /etc/squid/squid.conf and put in this
acl block_domains dstdomain .888
acl block_domains dstdomain .anime
acl block_domains dstdomain .bitcoin
acl block_domains dstdomain .blockchain
acl block_domains dstdomain .coin
acl block_domains dstdomain .crypto
acl block_domains dstdomain .dao
acl block_domains dstdomain .eth

Then add a rule
http_access deny block_domains

Then save and restart squid

Thanks for your response, but that rule does not block domains or extensions of web3 decentralized domains. This rule only works for normal domains (.com, .net, etc.) that can be resolved using DNS
